# How to prove this formula using sums?

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I need to prove this formula

$$\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y=\sin(x+y)$$

using sums

$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$$\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{2n!}$$

My attempt to solve it:

$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{{}={}}\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y \\[10pt]
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n\cdot y^{2n}}{2n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{2n!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n\cdot y^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \\[10pt]
& =\sum_{n}^{\infty }\sum_{k}^{n}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}y^{2(n-k)}}{2(n-k)!}+\sum_{n}^{\infty }\sum_{k}^{n}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{2k!}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}y^{2(n-k)+1}}{(2(n-k)+1)!} \\[10pt]
& =\text{ ?}
\end{align}
$$

Now I don't know how to continue. I tried to do some "magic" with binomial coefficients but it wasnt successful.

Thanks for help

Comment: I changed $sin x cos y$ to $\sin x \cos y$, etc.  That is standard.

Comment: It is much easier using that $\cos x=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and $\sin x=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ which is by the way directly equivalent to the sums using the exponential series. What you're trying to do comes down to reproving the functional equation $e^{x+y}=e^x e^y$.

Comment: @TooOldForMath : But if an assigned exercise says this is how it is to be done, then the option you suggest is not available.  And it's worth knowing how to do it this way too.

Comment: The final answer should look like $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \cdot (x+y)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$ Maybe that will show you how to split things apart with the binomial coefficients you've already played with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start at the other end:
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(x+y) & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x+y)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k x^k y^{n-k} \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \left(n!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}\cdot \frac{y^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Next, I'd rearrange the sum:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0} ^\infty (a_\ell b_m) = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \left( a_\ell \sum_{m=0}^\infty b_m\right)
$$

That last step works because $a_\ell$ does not chagne as $m$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$.  Then that lass sum does not change as $\ell$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, so we can write
$$
\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty a_\ell\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty b_m\right)
$$
and so on.

Why does the first rearrangement of the sum work?  There you need to look at why either way of writing the sum goes through the whole list of pairs of nonnegative integers.